Player1 isn't able to see Player2 in Photon-PUN
I was trying to make a multiplayer game using Photon-PUN, but there is an issue which I am facing.
Player1[the player which created the room] instantiated in the game then Player2.
The problem is that only Player2 can see Player1, Player1 can't see Player2

You can see that both the players are looking at each other but only Player2[which joined later] can see Player1 but Player1 can't see Player2
I am also encountering this warning error in the console whenever I move the Player2(player in Build).
Received OnSerialization for view ID 2001. We have no such PhotonView! Ignore this if you're joining or leaving a room. State: Joined

Source Code
NetworkManager (It connect to the server and create lobby and load lobby)
using UnityEngine;
using Photon.Pun;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class NetworkManager : MonoBehaviourPunCallbacks
{
    
    void Start()
    {
        Connect();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        
    }

    public void Connect(){
        PhotonNetwork.ConnectUsingSettings();
        if(PhotonNetwork.IsConnected){
            Debug.Log("Server Connected");
        }
    }

    public override void OnConnectedToMaster(){
        PhotonNetwork.JoinLobby();
    }

    public override void OnJoinedLobby()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(1);
    }
}

RoomManager (It create room via createInput field and join room via joinInput and load the game scene)
using Photon.Pun;
using UnityEngine;
using TMPro;

public class RoomManager : MonoBehaviourPunCallbacks
{
    [SerializeField] private TMP_InputField createInput;
    [SerializeField] private TMP_InputField joinInput;

    void Awake(){
        PhotonNetwork.AutomaticallySyncScene = true;
    }
    
    public void CreateRoom(){
        PhotonNetwork.CreateRoom(createInput.text);
    }

    public void JoinRoom(){
        PhotonNetwork.JoinRoom(joinInput.text);
    }

    public override void OnJoinedRoom()
    {
        PhotonNetwork.LoadLevel(2);
    }
}

GameManager (This instantiate the player)
using UnityEngine;
using Photon.Pun;

public class GameManager : MonoBehaviourPunCallbacks
{
    [SerializeField] private GameObject player;

    [SerializeField] private float minX, maxX, minY, maxY;

    void Start(){
        Vector2 randomPosition = new Vector2(Random.Range(minX, maxX), Random.Range(minY, maxY));
        PhotonNetwork.Instantiate(player.name, randomPosition, Quaternion.identity);
    }

}

PlayerController (This control the player movement)
using UnityEngine;
using Photon.Pun;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviourPunCallbacks
{
    public float speed;
    public float rotSpeed;
    
    void Start()
    {
        if(!photonView.IsMine){
            GetComponentInChildren<Camera>().enabled = false;
            GetComponentInChildren<AudioListener>().enabled = false;
        }
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if(photonView.IsMine){
            if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W)){
                gameObject.transform.position += transform.forward * speed * Time.deltaTime;
            }

            if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S)){
                gameObject.transform.position += -transform.forward * speed * Time.deltaTime;
            }

            if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A)){
                gameObject.transform.Rotate(0, -rotSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0);
            }

            if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D)){
                gameObject.transform.Rotate(0, rotSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0);
            }
        }
    }
}


Instead of instantly moving to scene 2
        PhotonNetwork.LoadLevel(2);

You need to wait for players to join then load level 2 from Master Client only.
Since you have set
        PhotonNetwork.AutomaticallySyncScene = true;

All other clients will load into the next scene together.
Modify your OnJoinedRoom as follow
public override void OnJoinedRoom()
{
    Invoke("MasterLoadNextScene", 5.0f);
}
public void MasterLoadNextScene(){
    if(PhotonNetwork.isMasterClient)
        PhotonNetwork.LoadLevel(2);
}

Ensure your player 2 joins room in 5 seconds here.

Hello @Abhay Thankyou very much, it worked.

but the tutorial I watched https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P6ia7AWjST0 , there was no such issue, why only I faced this issue?

It's probably because Photon is always updating. The video seems to be 4 years old and if you take a look at version history you'll notice changes made to PhotonView as well for example
v2.28.2 (03. March 2021)
Fixed: A potential issue with the execution order of the PhotonView component. It now sets it's own execution order to -16000 to get initialized before other scripts (especially on scene loading).
So maybe this is something that have changed over the time.

Make sure you instantiate the player only after the network connection is fully established. Update your GameManager script's Start method to include this check:
if (PhotonNetwork.IsConnectedAndReady)
{
    Vector2 randomPosition = new Vector2(Random.Range(minX, maxX), Random.Range(minY, maxY));
    PhotonNetwork.Instantiate(playerPrefab.name, randomPosition, Quaternion.identity);
}
else
{
    Debug.LogError("PhotonNetwork is not connected and ready");
}


NO it is not working. It always show the log error message to the other player when I try to join.
